# Sum expression in github action run-name

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to set dynamic name to workflow run that has a number. The number should be calculated using an expression.

```
run-name: Perform Operation with ID [SOME_GITHUB_VAR + 1]
```

Is there a way to perform the above sum operation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

The `run-name` can include some [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators) and can reference only the `github` and `inputs` contexts:

```
run-name: Deploy to ${{ inputs.deploy_target }} by @${{ github.actor }}
```

Unfortunately, GitHub Actions don't support math operations inside expressions. So, it's impossible to perform such a calculation for the value of the `run-name` option.

It's possible for the `name` value for a job step. You can add up these two numbers in a script and then set it as an environment variable.

**Example:**

```
name: 'Sum expression'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: run number with offset
        env:
          NUM: ${{ github.run_number }}
        run: |
          echo "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER_WITH_OFFSET=$(($NUM + 200))" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: 'Perform Operation with ID ${{ env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER_WITH_OFFSET }}'
        run: echo "Success!"
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

For more details, read the [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) article.

Reference: [How to add two numbers](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25386).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it in `run-name` ?

Comment: It does not seem possible to access "env" in "run-name". I got the message:

"The workflow is not valid. .... Unrecognized named-value: 'env'"

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible for the `run-name` option. Updated my answer providing more clarification